# Confused about the formatting of a ratio problem.

Tags: definition, ratio

I got this ratio problem:

> $$6:2::8:x$$

As someone who has a difficult time with even basic math, I'm kind of confused about this bit `::` 
Would that be the same as saying $6:2 = 8:x$?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same.

Comment: I once saw this symbol in Conic Sections by Apollonius of Perga.

Comment: It is the same as an equal sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes both are same.

One other way to do -

1st term × 4th term = 2nd term × 3rd term

6x = 2 × 8

6x = 16

Solve for x.